# Unit test error to API that call an external web service

Tags: c#, api, unit-testing

develop an WCF web API and all of functionalities pass the test but got some problem in one of unit test functions. Here is the details.

A class in WCF service calls an external SOAP web service. The SOAP service works fine and all of APT testing with WCF success. However, run unit test against this class got exception "System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException" with error message "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'external-service-url'.".  The unit test and API test are in the same machine and connection to the external service is https without client certificate required. why API test to call external serivice success but unit test failure?

Anyone can tell what is the problem and help me to go to right direction to resolve it?

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. Usually, unit tests are supposed to isolate their dependencies. This means your unit test should not call the actual external endpoint. It should call a mockup instead. In a perfect world, your class does not even know about the external endpoint, only of an interface to it, and your application uses dependency injection to provide the real api in production, and a fake api for unit testing.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR, _in a perfect world_ you will mockup only dependencies which makes tests slow. Since we are _in a perfect world_, where another server setup and call will takes milliseconds you don't need to mockup anything ;).

Answer (score 0):

As matter of fact, the unit test is testing the service function that dependence is the external service.

The API and the unit testing is in the same solution and run in the same local workstation, I just could not understand how the API runs perfectly without issue to reach the external service but when unit test this function without reach API through interface, the external reject the connection. I need to understand this where is the difference can prevent the the same function to make connection. Did someone see similar issue?